# Why does this childNodes give me that strange output?

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined, nodes

Why when i log the `tagName` of all the nodes in a specific node list it gives me this repeating `undefined` feedback ?

This is the part of the code i'm extracting nodes from :

**index.html**

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
    <div id="textInfo">
        <ul>    
            <li>            
                <label for="firstName"  class="mainLabel">First Name : </label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>
                <span>This must be filled</span>
            </li>    
            <li>    
                <label for="lastName"  class="mainLabel">Last Name : </label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"></input>
                <span>This must be filled</span>
            </li>    
            <li>    
                <label for="email"  class="mainLabel">E-mail : </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></input>
                <span>This must be filled</span>
            </li>                            
        </ul>
    </div>​
```

**script.js**

```
var myForm = document.forms["contactForm"];
eventUtil.add(myForm, "submit" , function(evt){
        var firstName = myForm.elements["firstName"];

        if(firstName.value == ""){      
            for(i=0; i < firstName.parentNode.childNodes.length ; i++){
                console.log("childNodes[" + i + "]: " + firstName.parentNode.childNodes[i].tagName);
            }
            eventUtil.preventDefault(evt);
        }
    });
```

and the output is :

```
childNodes[0]: undefined
childNodes[1]: LABEL
childNodes[2]: undefined
childNodes[3]: INPUT
childNodes[4]: undefined
childNodes[5]: SPAN
childNodes[6]: undefined
```

Why does it give me that `undefined` output repeatedly ?

Comment: Whitespace between DOM nodes is considered to be a node (textNode) itself by most browsers (except IE).

Comment: So, is there a way to avoid this ? other than stacking all elements next to each other in the HTML ?

Comment: @Rafael You could programmatically remove all the whitespace text nodes, but you would be better off just stacking them. (You can just put an angled bracket on the next line: the whitespace in an element doesn't do anything.)

Comment: @Rafael I'd suggest separating tasks: filling your array with non-text childNodes first, then looping over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i < firstName.parentNode.childNodes.length ; i++){
    var currNode=firstName.parentNode.childNodes[i];
    if(currNode.nodeType==1){
        console.log("childNodes[" + i + "]: " + currNode.tagName);
    }                
}
```

you can check nodeType (Node.ELEMENT_NODE == 1) to select Element only.